# Insert Multiple Records Dynamically in Coldfusion

Tags: sql, coldfusion, listbox

I have an EditBlogPost page. Within this page, the user can edit the "Title", "Body", and other objects. The only portion I'm struggling with is allowing the user to edit the BlogTags associated with a "BlogPost".

My method for doing this is using a bind Function to fill a list box with the tags currently associated with a specific BlogPost. I also have filled another list box, using a bind function, with tags not currently associated with a specific BlogPost.

```
Tags: <cfSelect Name="Tags" id ="Tags"
                bind="cfc:EditBlogTag.getData({BlogID@click})" 
                multiple="yes" 
                style="Width:150px" size="6" 
                value="TagID" display="Tag">
      </cfselect>

      <cfSelect Name="Tags2" id ="Tags2" style="Width:150px" 
              bind="cfc:EditBlogTag.getData2({BlogID@click})" 
              value="TagID" 
              display="Tag" 
              multiple="yes" 
              size="6" readonly="yes" >
      </cfselect>
```

When a BlogPost is chosen, and the list boxes fill, the user can move tags from one list box to another using arrow buttons.

```
<input type="button" id="moveRight" 
      value="&gt;" onclick="moveOptions('Tags','Tags2')">
<input type="button" id="moveLeft" 
      value="&lt;" onclick="moveOptions('Tags2','Tags')">
```

Everything I have listed up to now works. The output page is where the problems begin.

On the output page, I first delete all tags associated with a BlogPost, using on the BlogID. This works as expected:

```
<CFQUERY name="DeleteTagData" datasource="TheBlog">
    DELETE FROM BlogTagJunction
    WHERE BlogID = <cfqueryparam value="#Form.BlogID#" 
                             list="true" 
                             cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric"/>
</CFQUERY>
```

The next part should insert every tag within the the list box consisting of the tags to be 
associated with the form.

```
<CFQUERY name="AddTagData" datasource="prpblog">
    INSERT INTO BlogJunction (BlogID, TagID)
    VALUES (
       <cfqueryparam value="#Form.BlogID#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric"/>
     , <cfqueryparam value="#Form.Tags#" list="true" cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric"/>
    )
</cfquery>
```

This results in the error message:

> [Macromedia][SequeLink JDBC Driver][ODBC Socket][Microsoft][ODBC
>   Microsoft Access Driver] Number of query values and destination fields
>   are not the same.

Which is from selecting more than one tag. How can I at least allow this function to accept multiple selected indexes? Preferably, I would like to have everything within the list box inserted, instead of the selecting each tag.

Each index should be a separate record:

```
For example:
PostID  |   TagID
1             2
1             3
1             4
2             2
2             3
```

Edit: My attempt at a cfloop for this case:

```
<CFQUERY name="AddTagData" datasource="TheBlog">
<cfloop list="#Form.Tags#" index="Tags">
            INSERT INTO Junction (BlogID, TagID)
            Values (<cfqueryparam value="#Form.BlogID#" list="true" cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric"/>,
            <cfqueryparam value="<cfoutput>Tags</cfoutput>" list="true" cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric"/>)
</cfloop>
        </cfquery>
```

Comment: If the user can select multiple options, somewhere along the lines you are going to have to loop through them.

Comment: Did I ever say it was not going to loop?

Comment: You can get around this by moving the cfquery tag into the loop. It will obviously run a separate query call per loop, but you won't get the error. Depending on the number of iterations, this could theoretically add a touch of latency since you're making more trips to the db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That cfquery (insert) statement is only going to insert one record, one with the blog post ID and ALL of the tag ids as one big comma-delimited list.

So you want to put that cfquery (insert) statement inside of a cfloop block that loops through the Form.Tags list so that you're creating a record with the blog post ID and the tag id of the current loop iteration.

Comment: Says I'm missing a semicolon. I have never needed to use one. I must have done the Cfloop incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

its telling you you're missing a semicolon, because it can only handle one insert statement, unless it's suffixed with a semicolon.

just add a semicolon after your insert statement, but BEFORE you close the loop. that way, each query will be closed off with a semicolon.